# remove a certain part of a text string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text, text-manipulation

I'm trying to remove some part of a string in order to isolate a value of a sentence.
I would like to store the thing that is liked in a var called `thingLoved`. So when you type "I love cats" you can have a `console.log(thingLoved)` = cats

In order do to that, I'm trying to remove `I love` from the first sentence so it only remains "apples".
In that exemple I can remove `love` but not `i love` (because there is a space I guess), I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for the help.

```js
function individuaLetters(e){
  e.each(function(){
    var letters = $(this).html().replace(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+,\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+$/).toLowerCase();
    console.log(letters);
      
    if (letters.includes("i love")) {
      var thingLoved = $(this).html().replace("i love","")
      console.log(thingLoved);
    };
  })
}

var text = $('div').find('.indiv');
individuaLetters(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="indiv">I love apples</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the issue is. Could you edit the question to include a better description of your goal.

Comment: its not clear what you want to do but if you want to remove space you can simply trim it using string.trim()

Comment: try `replace("I love","")`, where `I` capitalized, as in the text.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov it's working with a capitalized I. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression with the alternator (|) in case you need to have more matches and case insensitive modifier (/i):

```js
function individuaLetters(e){
  e.each(function(){
    var letters = $(this).html().replace(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+,\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+$/).toLowerCase();
    console.log(letters);
      
    if (letters.includes("i love")) {
      var reg = /i love/i
      var thingLoved = $(this).html().replace(reg,"")
      console.log(thingLoved);
    };
  })
}

var text = $('div').find('.indiv');
individuaLetters(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="indiv">I love apples</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: yep, that's working and, you are right, will give more modularity.
Also, since we are here, do you know if I can expand that to remove everything else just to keep `apples` so if I type `hello, I love apples bye` the output will still be `apples` ?

Comment: You can have a list that will act as a matcher. For eg ['apples', 'banana', 'strawberry'] you can match the input string with this list and get only apples.

Comment: yep, it brings a lot of complexity, since the person says `I love bananas` it won't work...
Guess i'll have to find another solution to do what I want.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A regex is probably the best way to go as per @Vishal Jain's answer, but this is a basic fix for what you were originally trying to do:

```js
function individuaLetters(e){
  e.each(function(){
    var letters = $(this).html().replace(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+,\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+$/).toLowerCase();
    console.log(letters);
      
    if (letters.includes("i love")) {
      var thingLoved = letters.replace("i love","") .trim();         
      console.log(thingLoved);     
    }
  })
}

var text = $('div').find('.indiv');
individuaLetters(text);
```

Bascially, you were trying to replace "i love" in the original html string, which in fact still had "I love" in it (i.e. you need to call `includes()` on the `letters` variable).